# Network providers in USA that can work on SIM900 or Ai thinker A9g GSM modules

Tags: gsm, sim900

I am working on a sensing device that is installed remotely, I want to send the data to my mobile phone via SMS. The GSM module I am using inside my device is Ai thinker a9g. I have tried a couple of sim cards but they are not supported. I wanted to know I there is a service provider that supports sms/ text message service on aforementioned gsm module?

Answer (score 1):

I had tried and it works. Make sure your sim card support GSM.
Also you have to change the code to make it work.

If you check the code you going to have something like this:

```
#define PDP_CONTEXT_APN       "cmnet"
#define PDP_CONTEXT_USERNAME  ""
#define PDP_CONTEXT_PASSWD    ""

Network_PDP_Context_t context = {
.apn        = PDP_CONTEXT_APN,
.userName   = PDP_CONTEXT_USERNAME,
.userPasswd = PDP_CONTEXT_PASSWD
};
```

You have to change the APN by the apn of your provider (with a quick google search you going to find it)

I am going to give you some:

- MetroPCS: fast.metropcs.com
- **Ting: wholesale**  (This is the one I'm using)
- Sprint:  cinet.spcs
- Tmobile:     fast.t-mobile.com

Username and Password are empty.